# How to transform equations in lines of matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

I'm having a big problem with this because my program create functions which I'd like compound a matrix determinant with them, this determinant is zero and they'll be another function that will be permition obtain normal modes.

For example:

I need find lamb, and sometimes I'll find 3,4,5...10... equations forming a matrix(n,n).

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from scipy.integrate import quad
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve
from sympy import roots, solve_poly_system

Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,lamb=sp.symbols('Y_1 Y_2 Y_3 lamb')
x=sp.Symbol('x')
y=(1-x**2)*Y_1 + x*(1-x**2)*Y_2 +(x**2-(1/9))*(x**2-1)*Y_3

y_line=y.diff(x)

#integration argument
j= y_line**2-lamb*y**2
J=sp.integrate(j,(x,-1,1))


#differentiations
J_1=J.diff(Y_1)
J_2=J.diff(Y_2)
J_3=J.diff(Y_3)

#finding the characteristic equation

A,B=sp.linear_eq_to_matrix([J_1,J_3],[Y_1,Y_3])
M = sp.Matrix(A)
det=M.det()
u=sp.solve(det, lamb)
v=sp.solve(J_2,lamb)
print('[lambda_2]=',v)
print('[lambda_1,lambda_3]=',u)
```

I managed to solve the problem and updated the program.

Comment: This description is VERY unclear.  You should edit your question with some specifics, and a minimal example of your code, and some comment on what specific difficulty you are having with it.

Comment: shouldn't your equation be  `.33 * lamb * Y_1`? The lack of multiplication makes this an incorrect setting

Comment: I made the changes

Comment: Mix sympy and numpy with caution; often they don't work together.  Are you using `quad`?